# How to prove the inequality $\left[ a^p+b^p \right]^{1/p}+\left[ c^p+d^p \right]^{1/p} \geq \left[ e^p+f^p \right]^{1/p}$

Tags: inequality

Suppose $a+c \geq e$ and $b+d \geq f$, How to prove the inequality $$\left[ a^p+b^p \right]^{1/p}+\left[ c^p+d^p \right]^{1/p} \geq \left[ e^p+f^p \right]^{1/p}$$ Where $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{R}$ , $p \geq 1$.

Thank you for Hints/ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Use Minkowski's inequality, then the given condition.